# Preventing multiple users from doing the same action

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have a swing desktop application that is installed on many desktops within a LAN. I have a mysql database that all of them talk to. At precisely 5 PM everyday, there is a thread that will wake up in each of these applications and try to back up files to a remote server. I would like to prevent all the desktop applications from doing the same thing.

The way I was thinking to do this was:

**After waking up at 5PM , all the applications will try to write a row onto a MYSQL table. They will write the same information. Only 1 will succeed and the others will get a duplicate row exception. Whoever succeeds, then goes on to run the backup program.**

My questions are:

1. Is this right way of doing things? Is there any better (easier) way? 
   *I know we can do this using sockets as well. But I dont want to go down that route... too much of coding also I would need to ensure that all the systems can talk to each other first (ping)*
2. Will mysql support such as a feature. My DB is INNO DB. So I am thinking it does. Typically I will have about 20-30 users in the LAN. Will this cause a huge overhead for the DB to handle.

Comment: Why not use a dedicated backup system that is not installed on the desktops?

Comment: Only one client should do the backup? Do you want to backup data stored on the desktop or data stored on the server?

Comment: @Gandalf - Thats difficult to do actually. Its a nice idea which we had thought of initially, but there is some user involvement during the backup. And if the dedicated user does not launch the app then the backup cant be taken.

Comment: "in each of these applications and try to back up files to a remote server". "in each", sounds like every client will do the backup. "to a remote server" sounds like it will be stored in the server. The question is well written.

Comment: @Puce - The backup data should be stored on a remote server - Amazon S3 in fact. All the clients have access to the same database and files (on a shared folder). So if the backup runs simultaneously on all the users' desktops, then they would essentially be backing up the same files again and again.

Answer (score 1):

If you could put an intermediate class in between the applications and the database that would queue up the results and allow them to proceed in an orderly manner you'd have it knocked.

It sounds like the applications all go directly against the database.  You'll have to modify the applications to avoid this issue.

I have a lot of questions about the design:

1. Why are they all writing "the same row"?  Aren't they writing information for their own individual instance?
2. Why would every one of them have exactly the same primary key?  If there was an auto increment or timestamp you would't have this problem.
3. What's the isolation set to on the database connection?  If it's set to SERIALIZABLE, you'll force each one to wait until the previous one is done, at the cost of performance.
4. Could you have them all write files to a common directory and pick them up later in an orderly way?

I'm just brainstorming now.

Comment: I think I might not have made my self clear in the question.. Sorry. An intermediate class is not possible since they are separate applications running on separate desktops. So unfortunately I cant queue up the requests. Hence I wanted to use the database to decide who wins actually. Whoever writes the record to the database first, wins! And they get to upload the data. The others dont.

Comment: Yes, you can create an intermediate class.  It would be listening on the network, the same way the database is.  Your apps would just write to the app instead of opening a JDBC connection and writing to the database.  That intermediary could queue up the requests.  Think of it as a service that sits between clients and the database. You're doing service oriented architecture that way.  Your current design, as written, is flawed - but then you already know that.

Comment: Ah! okay.. thats a nice idea, but unfortunately that would create an installation problem for me though. I would now, need to ensure that in the server where the database runs, a java program runs too. And this java program would need to be created as a windows service and has to start up with the system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to backup server data not client data.

I recommend to use a 3-tier architecture using Java EE.
You could use a Timer Service then to trigger the backup.

Though usually a backup program is an independent program e.g. started by a cron job on the server. But again: you'll need a server to do this properly, not just a shared folder.

Comment: Sorry Puce.. I didnt get that. I would like to backup data stored on a client desktop onto a server. The application that I have installed on the client system is a swing application. The swing application needs to backup data onto a server - The Amazon S3 to be precise.

Comment: Again: do you want to backup the server data (the data on the shared folder accessed by all application and thus should only be backuped once) or data stored on the client in which case you probably want to backup the data for all the clients, not just for one client?

Comment: Ah okay.. we are talking about the same thing. Yes I would like to backup data stored in the shared folder onto Amazon S3. There is NO data stored on the client desktop alone that I want to backup. But as mentioned in comment to the answer by duffymo I would find it difficult installing a cron job on the server and starting the backup from there, since there is a user involvement in this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would suggest. Instead of having all clients wake up at the same time and trying to perform the backup, stagger the time at which they wake up.

So when a client wakes up
- It will check some table in your DB (MYSQL) to see if a back up job has completed or is running currently. If the job has completed, the client will go on with its normal duties. You can decide how to handle the case when the job is running.
- If the client finds that the back up job has not been run for the day, it will start the back up job. At the same time will modify the row to indicate that the back up job has started. Once the back up has completed the client will modify the table to indicate that the back up has completed.

This approach will prevent a spurt in network activity and can also provide a rudimentary form of failover. So if one client fails, another client at a later time can attempt the backup. (this is a bit more involved though. Basically it comes down to what a client should do when it sees that a back up job is on going).

Comment: Thats a nice idea. But we have an issue implementing that. Sorry I keep coming up with constraints after someone has answered. The requirement is the user gets to choose the time he is comfortable running a backup. There is a master user who will choose when the backup from his office should get taken. This will apply to all other users in the office. But ultimately, one of them should succeed. So although the idea is a great one, it would negate the user requirement. Could you tell me if there is any issue with the approach I had suggested above?

Comment: Then why not have the user also designate a client that will handle the back up? That way the user is aware of the machine that is handling the backup, so will ensure that its not shutdown etc. 
There is no issue as such with the approach that you have mentioned. I guess you have a unique constraint setup on some table so only one client can successfully insert a row. This will definitely work, there will be a sudden spurt at one point in time but that should be easily handled by MySQL.