# websocket to prevent multiple insert?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, socket.io

I'm designing a reservation system. How can I handle such case if multiple users book the same time slot at the same time? do I have to use websocket? as I know in nosql db there's already a findOneAndUpdate function where it's not possible to insert redundant id into a db.

Comment: Thats a opinion based question and off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in SQL but I've had a read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256659/preventing-multiple-users-from-doing-the-same-action) and this may be a possible solution:

When booking, the user will try to write a row onto a MYSQL table. They will write the same information. Only 1 will succeed and the others will get a duplicate row exception. Whoever succeeds, then goes on to book.

This is only 1 possible solution, and may not be the best. I also know you are using noSQL, but I presume that the premise would be the same.

Good luck!